# Custom JSTL function always returns false

Tags: java, spring, jstl

This snippet loops through a global list of `testContainerCommand.testContainerLocationList`. For each location, it will see if it's present in the main object's location list  `testContainerCommand.testContainer.testContainerLocationList`.

In both classes it's a property that looks like this: `private Set<TestContainerLocation> testContainerLocationList = new HashSet<TestContainerLocation>(0);`.

Current debugging shows that `testContainerCommand.testContainer.testContainerLocationList` has two items

form.jsp

```
<p>Number of locations: ${fn:length(testContainerCommand.testContainer.testContainerLocationList)}</p>

<!-- currently shows 2 --> 

<c:forEach items="${testContainerCommand.testContainerLocationList}" var="loc" varStatus="status">

    <!-- ${cfn:containsSet(testContainerCommand.testContainer.testContainerLocationList,loc)} -->

    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${cfn:containsSet(testContainerCommand.testContainer.testContainerLocationList,loc)}">
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

My custom.tld file:

```
<function>
    <name>containsSet</name>
    <function-class>org.test.utils.Compare</function-class>
    <function-signature>boolean containsSet(java.util.Set,java.lang.Object)
    </function-signature>
</function>
```

My Custom.java file:

```
public class Compare {

    public static boolean containsSet(Set s, Object o){
        return s.contains(o);       
    }
}
```

TestContainer XML Hibernate mappings:

```
...
<set name="testContainerLocationList" table="test_container_location_lookup"
 inverse="false" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="all">
    <key>
        <column name="id" not-null="true"/>
    </key>
    <many-to-many entity-name="org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation">
        <column name="location_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-many>
</set>
...
```

Why is it that it's always returning false? Do I have to cast the objects before comparing them?

**Update #1**

I ran the following test code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try{
            List<TestContainerLocation> testContainerLocationList = session.createQuery("from TestContainerLocation").list();
            TestContainer testContainer = (TestContainer)session.createQuery("from TestContainer where id = 12").list().get(0);

            for(TestContainerLocation l: testContainerLocationList){
                System.out.println(Compare.containsSet(testContainer.getTestContainerLocationList(), l));
            }
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e){
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
        session.close();

    }
}
```

Which output (as expected):

```
true
true
false
false
false
```

**Update #2**

Web Flow file:

```
<view-state id="form" view="/dbtest/form" model="testContainerCommand">
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate
            expression="testContainerAction.getTestContainer(testContainerCommand, flowRequestContext)" />
        <evaluate
            expression="testContainerAction.getTestContainerLocationList(testContainerCommand, flowRequestContext)" />
    </on-entry>
    <transition on="submit" to="saveForm" />
    <transition on="display" to="display" />
</view-state>
```

TestContainerAction.java

```
public void getTestContainer(TestContainerCommand cmd, RequestContext requestContext) throws Exception{

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) requestContext.getExternalContext().getNativeRequest();

        //get param
        String id = request.getParameter("id");

        //param present
        if(! StringUtils.isEmpty(id) && StringUtils.isNumeric(id)){
            cmd.setTestContainer(testContainerDao.getTestContainerById(Long.parseLong(id)));
        }
        //no param
        else{
            TestContainer t = new TestContainer();
            t.setTestContainerType(new TestContainerType());
            t.setTestContainerLocationList(new HashSet<TestContainerLocation>(0));
            cmd.setTestContainer(t);
        }

        cmd.setTestContainerTypeList(testContainerTypeDao.getTestContainerTypeList());
        cmd.setTestContainerLocationList(testContainerLocationDao.getTestContainerLocationList());
    }

public List<TestContainerLocation> getTestContainerLocationList(TestContainerCommand cmd, RequestContext requestContext) throws Exception{
        cmd.setTestContainerLocationList(testContainerLocationDao.getTestContainerLocationList());
        return cmd.getTestContainerLocationList();
    }
```

**Update #3**

TestContainerLocation class:

```
public class TestContainerLocation implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1381290537575465609L;

    private Integer locationId;
    private String locationName;
    private Set<TestContainer> testContainer = new HashSet<TestContainer>(0);

    public Integer getLocationId() {
        return locationId;
    }
    public void setLocationId(Integer locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }
    public String getLocationName() {
        return locationName;
    }
    public void setLocationName(String locationName) {
        this.locationName = locationName;
    }
    public Set<TestContainer> getTestContainer() {
        return testContainer;
    }
    public void setTestContainer(Set<TestContainer> testContainer) {
        this.testContainer = testContainer;
    }


}
```

I found a site that seems to talk about what DPM was saying:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html

Here's the content of my previously abbreviated forEach:

```
<ul>
        <c:forEach items="${testContainerCommand.testContainerLocationList}" var="loc" varStatus="status">
            <!-- ${cfn:containsSet(testContainerCommand.testContainer.testContainerLocationList,loc)} -->
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${cfn:containsSet(testContainerCommand.testContainer.testContainerLocationList,loc)}">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="location${loc.locationId}" name="location"
                        value="${loc.locationId}" 
                        checked="checked" />
                        <label for="location${loc.locationId}">${loc.locationName}</label></li>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="location${loc.locationId}" name="location"
                        value="${loc.locationId}" />
                        <label for="location${loc.locationId}">${loc.locationName}</label></li>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
```

**Update #4**

New compare function, doing a simple toString() on incoming objects:

```
public class Compare {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Compare.class);

    public static boolean containsSet(Set s, Object o){

        logger.info(s.toString()+":"+o.toString());

        return s.contains(o);       
    }
}
```

Output of said logging:

```
INFO : org.test.utils.Compare - [org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation@6c5bdfae, org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation@6a7be687]:org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation@13de6be9
INFO : org.test.utils.Compare - [org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation@6c5bdfae, org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation@6a7be687]:org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation@6f7e982f
INFO : org.test.utils.Compare - [org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation@6c5bdfae, org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation@6a7be687]:org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation@60396ed8
INFO : org.test.utils.Compare - [org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation@6c5bdfae, org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation@6a7be687]:org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation@5a9c5842
INFO : org.test.utils.Compare - [org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation@6c5bdfae, org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation@6a7be687]:org.test.vto.TestContainerLocation@4e668387
```

**Solution:**

As per the accepted solution, I simply had to override the equals and hashCode methods in my TestContainerLocation class.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(this == obj)
        return true;
    if(obj == null)
        return false;
    if(getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    TestContainerLocation in = (TestContainerLocation) obj;

    return  getLocationId() == in.getLocationId() 
            && (getLocationName() == in.getLocationName() 
            || (getLocationName() != null && getLocationName().equals(in.getLocationName())));
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;

    result = prime * result + ((getLocationId() == null) ? 0 : Long.valueOf(getLocationId()).hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((getLocationName() == null) ? 0 : getLocationName().hashCode());

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How do you know it returns false? You don't do anything inside the c:when tag. How are equals and hashCode defined? What are the objects in the set and what is the object you pass to containsSet()?

Comment: Did you exclude JSTL/EL from being suspect by executing `s.contains(o)` as a regular Java application? There's namely one pretty obvious basic Java beginners mistake which may cause this problem, but you've nowhere in the question explicitly excluded it from being the cause.

Comment: @jb-nizet first parameter is Set<TestContainerLocation>, second is a single instance of TestContainerLocation. I also added the HTML comment output that shows that it's false... that's what I'm basing myself on.

Comment: @balusc I edited my question to show that I had an HTML comment outputting the boolean value of my function, which shows false, before the choose. And I will confirm your assumption that I'm a beginner to Java :) And no, I didn't run it stand alone to see the results, never occurred to me.

Comment: Please run this as plain Java code, not as JSP/JSTL/EL code. Put this code in a plain Java class with a `main()` method. If it also fails, then the problem is not in JSP/JSTL/EL at all. Just think logically.

Comment: @balusc I ran the test per your suggestion which shows that two of the comparisons return true (see update).

Comment: can you add logging or a breakpoint in your contains method so you would actually see which objects it gets?

Comment: @eis I could but I'm struggling at how exactly to do this... most specifically, the incoming Set. Should I simply loop it? Or specifically an element in the Set?

Comment: no need to loop it, just log the contents as it is. Collections have pretty decent toString() methods that will print out the contents.

Comment: @eis toString() seems to reveal that objects are not equal? I'm not overriding equals() and hashCode() yet. See update #4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post your TestContainerLocation class, which would be helpful to answering this question. It looks like you may not have overridden equals() or hashCode(). TestContainerLocation would use the Object implementations of these, so your java example code from update 1 would work (they're actually the same objects), but if you're retrieving objects from hibernate at different times, they won't be Object.equal, and your call from the JSP will return false.

Comment: my TestContainerLocation class has a reference to TestContainer to meet the requirements for a many-to-many relationship in hibernate. Should the override take into account of this or can I omit this for the context I'm using the equals method?